# error when running synaptic: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment cannot open display

Tags: gtk, synaptic, xdg

After installing synaptic by typing `sudo apt-get synaptic`
I tried to run it with `sudo synaptic` and I am getting this error:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment
synaptic (4865):Gtk warning**:cannot open display
```

Comment: it gives invalid operation @Zanna

Comment: `synaptic` needs to run under an X windows server (`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is set by the server, to help programs communicate with it) - are you tring to run `synaptic` in a TTY?